# Extension method in c# calling a database - good idea?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have the following code:

```
public static bool IsEuropeanPolicyPlanNumber(this string planNumber)
{
    var result = MyEuropeanPolicyPlanNumberCheck(planNumber)
    return result;
}
```

It seems that is no longer an option, which means before we could understand which country the policy originated by its prefix. However, things are changing that are no longer guaranteed We thought to validate this based on what returns from our DB. A quick fix will be to call within the scope of our extension method:

```
public static bool IsEuropeanPolicyPlanNumber(this string planNumber)
{
    var result = false;
    var country = Repository.CountryForPolicyQuery(planNumber);
    result = MyCountryCheck(country);
    return result;
}
```

Is this a good idea, or it goes against the guidelines provided here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/extension-methods

Note: Repository is a static class

I believe that extension methods should not be driven by any state. I'm asking the community what they think about this.

Comment: What do you mean by "It seems that is no longer an option."? Note that even when this is clearer, it sounds like it's going to be an opinion-based question (and therefore off-topic).

Comment: Extending something common like a string with a context depending extension. Yes that sounds unexpected.

Comment: I'd be more worried about your repository being a static class. How do you do things like inject in a connection? Monitoring?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated my post. Opinion-based question when asking for what is the best practice? Where should I ask then?

Comment: @SMagistri-Utmost: It's still really unclear. (What was the situation before, and what's broken now?) But it'll still be opinion-based and therefore off-topic. I don't know where you're best asking it, but not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This was flagged as opinion based but i don't think it is -- this function clearly has no place in the string class and any OOP with experience would say so. @JonSkeet

Comment: "Is this a good idea" is asking for an opinion, not a fact.

Comment: @JonSkeet What I'm asking is whether it is a good idea to implement an extension method that is calling a database or not. As for your question, the business is changing so is the way those policy numbers are generated. I'm not sure why it is interesting for you to know that. I think you already made up your mind about closing this and I have already got my answer thanks to CodeCaster and Hogan who are more helpful than you. Stackoverflow is the place to ask at the end :)

Comment: My opinion if you extend your Repository with that methods then yes it does something expected and its absolutely ok. Its just a detail that its an extension method and not a "real" method. Extending a string then its unexpected but from your question is sounds like an inherited problem. It was this way already before adding the db access. So without design changes i would suggest that you hide that extension method at least in some specific namespace fitting the "EuropeanPolicyPlanNumber" context ...

Comment: .. so that not everyone everywhere in this project using a string is concerned with the "what the heck is this for" problem.

Comment: "Stackoverflow is the place to ask at the end" - please don't take "I got an answer" as evidence of "my question was on-topic". That's definitely *not* the case. There are questions which *shouldn't* be answered but *are* answered every day.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a good idea, or it goes against the guidelines

[The guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/extension-methods):

> ❌ AVOID frivolously defining extension methods, especially on types you don't own.

I don't know how frivolous the authoring of that extension method was, but you definitely don't own string, so you fail the first check.

What's wrong with a static class `PlanNumber` with a static method `IsEuropeanPolicy(string planNumber)`?

> Note: Repository is a static class

You don't do dependency injection? And why isn't `CountryForPolicyQuery` async?

Comment: It would be so great to get an update on the guidelines they feel a bit dated and i miss the comments of some MVP guys like in the printed version :(

Comment: @Magnus for example on an interface. But the text below that also mentions to consider creating an instance method instead.

Comment: @Ralf yeah those (coding/style) guidelines could use an update.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good idea.  Just think about how objects work -- an object defines all the operations on objects of that type.  Here you have something that does not apply to objects of type string but to a minor sub-set of objects of type string -- those that have a plan number.

Best practices would be to create a new object -- of type PlanNumber.  On that object you can add extensions and properties and all the business rules you want.

Sting type is not the place for this code -- put it in an object of the correct type.